# Angular Google Map not getting lat and lng variable

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I am new to Angular, and I have been trying to figure this out for hours. I can't get the lat and lng variables to return the number properly when I get them from JSON.

I am getting JSON from here: https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users

Here is the component.html...

```
<div *ngIf="user$">

<ul>

  <li><strong>Lat:</strong> {{ lat }}</li>
  <li><strong>Lng:</strong> {{ lng }}</li>

</ul>

  <agm-map [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng">
    <agm-marker [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng"></agm-marker>
  </agm-map>

</div>
```

It works as it should in the list and map elements when I set the values in the variables this way.

Working component.ts

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  user$: any;

  constructor(private data: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.route.params.subscribe( params => this.user$ = params.id)
  }

  ngOnInit() :void {
    this.data.getUser(this.user$).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.user$ = data 
        console.log(this.lat, this.lng);

      } 
    )

  }
        lat: number = -37.3159;
        lng: number = 81.1496;

}
```

But as soon as I try to get values from JSON the variables return as the string, and the map and the marker don't work but the list element does.

Not working component.ts

```
export class DetailsComponent implements OnInit {

  user$: any;
  lat: number;
  lng: number;

  constructor(private data: DataService, private route: ActivatedRoute) { 
    this.route.params.subscribe( params => this.user$ = params.id)
  }

  ngOnInit() :void{
    this.data.getUser(this.user$).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.user$ = data 
        this.lat = this.user$.address.geo.lat;
        this.lng = this.user$.address.geo.lng;
        console.log(this.lat, this.lng);
      } 
    )

  }

}
```

When I hover over the lat and lng variables in the Visual Studio Code either way, it looks identical and it says **(property) DetailsComponent.lng : number** or **(property) DetailsComponent.lng : number**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because `agm` expects an integer value and you provide a string. I think the best way to convert it into number value (in case if your number format uses dot `.` (not comma `,`), use a `+` sign:

```
this.lat = +this.user$.address.geo.lat;
this.lng = +this.user$.address.geo.lng;
```

Comment: I also got it to work this way. I placed an function in the ts file.     ConvertString(value){
return parseFloat(value)
} and changed the html to [latitude]="ConvertString(lat)" and [longitude]="ConvertString(lng)".

Comment: p.s. I wouldn't write a dollar sign here `this.user$ = data`. Thats a convention for streams, like Observable. It might confuse other programmers